# Does typescript allow the addition of "traits" to an existing array of objects?

Tags: typescript

I have a few object types that I want to manipulate an array of said object types.

```
type AB = { a:number, b:number}
type CD = { c:number, d:string}
type DE = { d:number, e:boolean}

let state: AB[] = []
function onStateChange(newState: AB[]) {
  console.log(newState)
  state = newState
}

function add(blank: AB ) {
  onStateChange([
    ...state,
    blank,
  ]);
}

function remove(index: number) {
  onStateChange([...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)]);
}

function update(index: number, updated: Partial<AB>) {
  onStateChange([...state.slice(0, index),
  { ...state[index], ...updated},
   ...state.slice(index + 1)]);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFA3lAhgLgHYFcC2ARhAE4A0UhOBxJAvgLABQokUAwgCJKpQDG1IqQoATTAGdgJAJbYA5oxbhonAKI80YvEPJQImQgHtDAGwjpsi5meBRJ6YPthwA2gF0e75gDNc2PsDShthQwQDKwA4Q7AAWFnIQABTYEADuEVGYzu4AlKjMUPzB4qYQAHQmhnLJaRmOOQV2kY48KenNEMxWTL7+gcEYIiKJhCYWANZZ8FB5KI3hHbHxSS6NhWUb9o5ka5Rj2OM7TIVuOQDcXcw+fgFBISQQ+IYAbkmyIhAAHlnatLPz2Dq0Ti8hWGzKW3K4hM0j4SQADBR3l8chRwZCITC4YlkZ8oABqKAARhypwuTG6vVuA1wYBEURx2A+3ygv2EUFp9McYigAAV0CRAugTAAeeAAPn+x1CgMWIISiRc6I6mNhCKRTJRR0KaGVURcuLcaI2nKiIjo2vWmxV0LVjOZBOJpPOlyYzCAA)

I am trying to have those add,remove,update methods applied to `state` something like this which provides additional methods that return modified copies of the original data

```
interface WithListManagement<T> {
  withAdd(blank: T ) : T[] {
    return [
      ...state,
      blank,
    ]);
  }
  withRemove(index: number) {
    return [...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)]);
  }
  withUpdate(index: number, updated: Partial<AB>) {
    return [...state.slice(0, index),
      { ...state[index], ...updated},
      ...state.slice(index + 1)]);
  }
}
```

so something like

```
let state: WithListManagement<CD> = []
function add(blank: CD ) {
  onStateChange(state.withAdd({c:1, d:'foo'});
}
```

Note I am trying to avoid modifying the Array prototype because I only want this to be applied to specific lists not all arrays.

UPDATE re: context.

Basically what I want to do is something similar to `default interface methods` in Java but also get the type erasure in Typescript.

So say I have the type `AB[]`, which has the standard `Array` methods like map,length, etc and being able to JSON.stringify().

I would like something like an `interface` or even `class` that would allow me to say something like `WithListManagement<AB>` which should have the same behaviour as `AB[]` with the additional methods I am describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing function implementation into the interface is not valid. Interface is just a type which gets erased in compilation time.

This is valid implementation of the interface:

```js
interface WithListManagement<T> {
  withAdd(blank: T): T[]
  withRemove(index: number): T[]
  withUpdate(index: number, updated: Partial<AB>): T[]
}

declare var someState:WithListManagement<number>

someState.withAdd(42) // ok
```

Hovewer, above implementation uses methods which is not super safe because methods are bivariant.
It is better to use arrow functions:

```js
interface WithListManagement<T> {
  withAdd: (blank: T) => T[]
  withRemove: (index: number) => T[]
  withUpdate: (index: number, updated: Partial<AB>) => T[]
}
```

Please provide more context what you want to achieve

**UPDATE**
You need to extend Array built in class.

```js
type AB = { a: number, b: number }

class WithListManagement<T> extends Array<T>{

    withAdd(blank: T) {
        return [
            ...this,
            blank,
        ];
    }
    withRemove(index: number) {
        return [...this.slice(0, index), ...this.slice(index + 1)];
    }
    withUpdate(index: number, updated: Partial<AB>) {
        return [...this.slice(0, index),
        { ...this[index], ...updated },
        ...this.slice(index + 1)];
    }
}

const state = new WithListManagement<AB>();

state.push({ a: 1, b: 2 }) // ok

//[{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 4 }]
const result = state.withAdd({ a: 3, b: 4 }) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFA3lAhgLigOwK4C2ARhAE4A0UR2%20xZUAvgFBMDGANugM5dQDqAS2AALADICuwALLoc6AOYQCEHMAA8AFQB8UCAA9gKgCa8YpUuhCatKFlHtQA7kOEwjRgBRFOOANbYNAEpUJgcwqFIIYDxSHCgAbVDw5IA6NJEJciTksO9ZXyycqABdAG5sxgrnEQAlJQB7ADcIDwEcI30aQhJSYNsiyOjYhLSUjK4UrnYBVhaABko2jr1AylHxyenZ1vb9KABqKABGQLKK5jDq4QBVMCN0Qx3lrroKKDw7h4gjbAAFdFIwAE6HYangWj6FTCgxicXi62EEk2M3mi12K0KOTQCIk8SW%20mKazSH3uhiMjExqXSiImUxRTz2hxOZzCzGYbHqOEkUEkXyQuAgjn4LnEkhkckUylUYLgWg8gXKTF5hhSYDwXGEHjQWGOlGoUAATIxggB6E1Qeq%20Fhm%20La7BHPXYI0MSh2qAAZkdUAALIxihyucAIhAuHh2EHkMqICkrm5PG7PVRsL6GKbzZaWCwgA)

**UPDATE 2. Extend from the Object**
In order to do it, you need to implement your custom iterator.

```js
type AB = { a: number, b: number }

class WithListManagement<T> extends Object {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this;
    }
    next() {
        return { value: 42 }
    }

    withAdd(blank: T) {
        return [
            ...this,
            blank,
        ];
    }

}

const state = new WithListManagement<AB>();
state.withAdd // ok
```

Comment: added it to the OP

Comment: side question... I know my OP was for an array. Can this be done with "objects?"  Like is there something like extends Object<T> ?

Comment: Sorry, out of my PC. Try to extend from Object. I have never done this before